# How to return all values of a collection when using Laravel whenEmpty

Tags: php, laravel, collections, eloquent, query-builder

I am new to Laravel and is trying to fix someone else' code.

I am selecting users (joining `users` table and `user_details` table) into `$users` collection. Then applying some filters/conditions into that. For example, when comparing mother tongue (string) with fluent languages (array), I use

```php
    $users->whereIn('users.motherTongue', $detail->fluentIn);
```

I also need to compare `user_details.fluentLanguage` with `$detail->fluentIn`. Both these fields are string arrays (text in DB). I don't think 'where' condition support this, so, I am trying this.

```php
    $fluentIn = $detail->fluentIn;
    $diff = $fluentIn->diff('user_details.fluentLanguage')->all();
    $users->whenEmpty(function ($diff) {
        return $users;
    });
```

Any idea how to fix this? Or is there any better way of doing this? I need to filter users by comparing `user_details.fluentLanguage` and `$detail->fluentIn`.

Comment: Maybe you need to share example data of `$users` to get feedback

Comment: @WahyuKristianto I just realised Ididnt share data type of both these fields. Corrected above. Other fields doesn't affect this answer and I believe it will be unecessarily complicated/confusing if I add all other fields.